# Where can I download the Castle Windsor WcfIntegration Facilities dll?

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

I would like to integrate Castle Windsor into a WCF project and have read that you can hook it up using the WcfIntegration facility but I am unable to find where to download the dll.

Can anyone help?

Comment: By the way, this answered my question about the NHibernate Facility as well. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the NHibernate Facility from nuget (http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration) now which is probably a better option than compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in NuGet now with all of the other 3.0 beta stuff.

Install-Package Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility

---

**Update**

Just to follow up, The one in nuget is targeted for Windsor 3.0 beta 1.  I found out the hard way that some of the other facilities do not yet support 3.0 beta 1.  Specifically, if you're using the NHibernate or AutoTx facilities, you need to stick with a WCF factility compiled for Windsor 2.  The latest one seems to be the Jul 29 2011 commit from the git repository, [available here](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.Wcf-READONLY/commits/master/).

This will have to suffice until the 3.0 versions of the other facilities are updated.  It's already being discussed on the [castle users group list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users).

Answer (score 6):

WCF Facility did not have an official release yet, as there are still few rough edges and issues we want to address before making the release. Your best option now is to either get the source using link provided in the other answer, or to get it from Horn website. The latter option is compiled against trunk version of other projects, so if you want to use released version of Windsor (2.1.1) you have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/Facilities/Wcf/trunk from http://www.castleproject.org/subversion.html you have to download the source and build it yourself apperently.