# Where to download Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll?

Tags: castle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I download the Castle Windsor WcfIntegration Facilities dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237755/where-can-i-download-the-castle-windsor-wcfintegration-facilities-dll)

I need `Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll` but don't know where I can downland it. Maybe merged with another assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only place to get it [is the build server](http://builds.castleproject.org/project.html?projectId=project32&tab=projectOverview), because there was no official release of the facility yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can download from Github and build it yourself

https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.Wcf

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference by using NuGet

Details  are here http://nuget.org/packages/Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility